# browser detection with modern web frameworks (meteor.js specifically)

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

So I am writing and app with meteor.js and I try to show it to somebody with an ancient browser. The site is all screwed up, probably because of a mix of unsupported CSS, javascript, and html features.

What is the best way to kick anyone to the curb without a moderately modern browser (IE9+ etc...)??

And before we get ahead of ourselves

- Firstly, I have no desire to do feature detection (I have no idea what features meteor requires although I see some suggestion it might even work on IE6)
- Secondly, I have no desire to test on outdated browsers (so even if feature detection would work I don't want to put in the effort to ensure that it works across any more than the latest browsers)
- Thirdtastically, Is it so wrong to just not want to put in any effort to support older browsers and to have no sympathy for people with them?

Comment: Conditional IE CSS styles and redirection to better browser download.

Comment: Fourthically, I don't know if thirdtastically is an actual word. But on topic, there's nothing wrong with not wanting to support older browsers. However, feature detection goes way beyond that. Latest Chrome has many more features and APIs than IE9-10, for example. If you site has way too many modern features, at some point it might break even on "modern" browsers. Then the definition of a "modern browser" loses its sense. Hence you do feature detection and progressive enhancement/graceful degradation.

Comment: Just do nothing. Let people who use IE8 and below or FF2 to worry.

Comment: The basis of the web is accessibility, it's about access to information. If you don't care about anyone using a browser older than say 12 months, fine. But don't be surprised if your traffic volume is significantly affected as a result. For many web users, the version of their browser is tied to their OS version, so while the browser is "free", an OS upgrade to get the latest version probably isn't.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's not like I don't want everyone to be able to use it. My main point is just that I am a one man shop and so I have to choose my efforts wisely. I am using a complex framework to be able to work at a higher level of abstraction but it this prevents me from testing or even knowing about the degradation of every feature. @llia I don't like the idea of it working like that, I'd rather say no you can't participate because you don't have the right gear than have them participate and get hurt.